# How to get custom cell object from Indexpath?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I tried the following code for getting custom cell.This code I used for the purpose of  UITableView cell Check ONLY ONE Row at a Time.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // if they are selecting the same row again, there is nothing to do, just keep it checked
    if ((seleectedIndex) != nil) {

        if indexPath == seleectedIndex {
            return
        }
        let oldCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: seleectedIndex!) as! MisstageTableViewCell
        if oldCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark {
            oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
            oldCell.buttonSelection.setImage(UIImage(named:"off")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for:.normal)
        }

    }
    // toggle old one off and the new one on
    let newCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MisstageTableViewCell
    if newCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none {
        newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
        newCell.buttonSelection.setImage(UIImage(named:"on")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for:.normal)
    }
    seleectedIndex = indexPath  // save the selected index path
}
```

My code is working fine.But When I scroll the table view (like up and down)then I clicked on any cell then I got the crash on the specific line

```
let oldCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: seleectedIndex!) as! MisstageTableViewCell
```

I don’t know what is the reason for crashing.Could you please help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni, I got last selected index in muy console like

Answer (score 1):

why are you updating the cell inside

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

You should do it in

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

First declare a variable as:

```
var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath!
```

didSelectRowAt should be modified as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if selectedIndexPath != nil {
        let tempIndexPath = selectedIndexPath
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath, tempIndexPath], with: .fade)
    }
    else {
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .fade)

    }
}
```

I don't know what you are doing in **cellForRowAt**. But it should be modified as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
    cell.buttonSelection.setImage(UIImage(named:"off")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for:.normal)
    if selectedIndexPath != nil && indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
        cell.buttonSelection.setImage(UIImage(named:"on")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for:.normal)
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Do not reload the entire table view just because a single row was selected. That kills the selection animation and it's very inefficient. You should just reload the current row and the previously selected row, if any.

Comment: Also, `selectedIndexPath` should be an optional, not an implicitly unwrapped optional

Comment: Your code doesn't handle the initial unselected state properly; it doesn't set `selectedIndexPath` in that case

Comment: it handles see func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

Comment: No, if `selectedIndexPath` is `nil` then it is never assigned to.

Comment: sorry my mistake forgot to do the assignment.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: reloadRows needs IndexPath array not an since indexPath, it will show error at this line,  tableView.reloadRows(at: selectedIndexPath, with: .fade)

Comment: sorry typing mistake

Answer (score 1):

You should not change the cell data inside `didSelectRow`, ideal solution would be to reload the rows based on selected indexPath and `check/unckeck` accessory type for the cell

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var selectedIndex: IndexPath?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MisstageTableViewCell
        if let selectedIndex = selectedIndex, indexPath.row == selectedIndex.row {
           cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
           let image = UIImage(named: "on")
           cell.buttonSelection.setImage(image!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        } else {
          cell.accessoryType = .none
          let image = UIImage(named: "off")

        }
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //selected the same indexPath then return
      if let selectedIndex = selectedIndex, selectedIndex == indexPath {
        return
      }

      if let selectedIndex = selectedIndex, selectedIndex != indexPath {
         let oldSelectedIndex = selectedIndex
        selectedIndex = indexPath
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [oldSelectedIndex, indexPath], with: .fade)
      } else {
        selectedIndex = indexPath
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are force unwrapping an optional.  If you select a cell then scroll and the selected cell is no longer on screen the system can remove it from memory and thus it will become nil.

```
if let oldCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: seleectedIndex!) as? MisstageTableViewCell {
    // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: 1) You *could* update the cell in `didSelect`, *but* since you have to handle the selection state in `cellForRowAt` anyway, you may as well simply reload that row and let the code in `cellForRowAt` handle it and eliminate the duplicated code. 2) the only reason you would obtain `oldCell` is to update it, so the update is implied

Comment: you could be tracking something else such as expanding cells where you do not want to reload but maybe use tableView.beginUpdates() and endUpdates(). @Paulw11

Answer (score 0):

The result of *tableView.cellForRow(at: seleectedIndex!)* returns is optional, so it`s can be nil